# Replace preg_replace modifier with preg_replace_callback

Tags: regex

I'm terrible with regular expressions. I'm trying to replace this:

```
$cleaned[0]['body'] = preg_replace('~&#x([0-9a-f]+);~ei', 'chr(hexdec("\\1"))', $cleaned[0]['body']);
$cleaned[0]['body'] = preg_replace('~&#([0-9]+);~e', 'chr("\\1")', $cleaned[0]['body']);
```

with preg_replace_callback
I try this:

```
$cleaned[0]['body'] = preg_replace_callback('~&#x([0-9a-f]+);~e', create_function ('$matches', 'return chr(hexdec($matches[1]));'), $cleaned[0]['body']);
$cleaned[0]['body'] = preg_replace_callback('~&#([0-9]+);~', create_function ('$matches', 'return chr($matches[1]);'), $cleaned[0]['body']);
```

Comment: What's your question?

Answer (score 0):

[`create_function()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.create-function.php) is often times disabled for security reasons since it executes an `eval()` call.  With [`preg_replace_callback()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace-callback.php), you should just be able to define your callable function as a parameter:

```
$cleaned[0]['body'] = preg_replace_callback(
  '~&#([0-9]+);~',
  function($matches) {
    return chr($matches[1]);
  },
  $cleaned[0]['body']
);
```